# "USB-Device not detected" - internal USB 2.0 ports

Tags: usb, drivers, motherboard, windows-11

I reclaimed my motherboard (ASUS ROG STRIX Z690-A GAMING WIFI D4) some time ago and installed a new one in my setup because I was having problems with overclocking and XMP among other things. Another problem was that my AIO (Corsair iCUE h150i elite lcd xt display) and my case fans (10x Lian Li SL 120 Inf) were always removed from the respective sofwares (iCUE and LConnect3) at the same time a few minutes after booting the PC, so I can no longer control them. I then always get a message from Windows that my USB devices are not recognized (but this refers exclusively to the internal USB2.0 pins, all external peripherals work fine). In the device manager they appear as an unknown USB device, where supposedly the device description cannot be read. With right-click and uninstall device and a reboot, the AIO and fans show up again in their software, but again only for a few minutes.

The two internal USB 2.0 ports are assigned as follows:
Y-cable (supplied by Corsair) into the motherboard, which splits to the USB 2.0 from the display and from the Corsair Commander Hub - as it is also described in the installation instructions.
cable into the motherboard and from there into the Lian Li hub, where the fans occupy 4 ports, as I can always chain three together.

What I have already tried:

- BIOS Update
- Fresh USB drivers installed
- Chipset driver installed
- Plugged in all cables in any constellation, also sometimes only single and without Y-cable
- Uninstalled and reinstalled iCUE and LConnect3 completely
- Checked all cables again, that they are tightly connected

I would be glad about further help, unfortunately I don't know any further, because my mainboard doesn't seem to have any broken ports, because the problem occurred with both, which I tested. They were also from different batches and about 6 months apart in manufacture.
I suspect it will be some driver problem. Or is it possibly common with Windows 11?

I will gladly provide more information as needed.

Thanks in advance!

Leonie